# Regex - How to recognize a String + white spaces + String

Tags: java, regex

I need to recognize some pattern which goes like this: 
[letters][some spaces][letters]

What I done so far is this:

```
String regex = "[a-zA-Z]\\s+[a-zA-Z]";
```

Comment: Add `+` for the character classes as well `String regex = "[a-zA-Z]+\\s+[a-zA-Z]+";`

Comment: Is plus is the argument for adding another pattern in the same one?

Comment: @nu11p01n73R I guess your comment is worth turning it into an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the requirement, you wrote *letters* (with a *s* at the end).

```
[letters][some spaces][letters]
```

So to do that you must be quantifying the character class as

```
String regex = "[a-zA-Z]+\\s+[a-zA-Z]+";
```

- `[a-zA-Z]+` Matches one or more letters. Here `+` is the quantifier which quantifies `[a-zA-Z]` One or more times.

  [**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/xA2gS8/1)

  Where as if you write `[a-zA-Z]\\s+[a-zA-Z]`, it would only match a single character before and after the space.

  [**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/xA2gS8/2)

---

If you want the entire string to follow this pattern, you must be adding anchors as well to the pattern as

```
String regex = "^[a-zA-Z]+\\s+[a-zA-Z]+$";
```

- `^` Anchors the regex at the start of the string.
- `$` Anchors the regex at the end of the string.
- These anchors ensure that immediatly following start of string, `^` number of letters occure, `[a-zA-Z]+` followed by space and again letters. The second group of letters is followed by end of string `$`

Comment: `[a-zA-Z]+ Matches one or more letters.` - when you are saying that, you mean that this pattern can be more than 1 ?

Comment: Yeah, it is same as writing `[a-zA-Z]` for infinite number of times. Please see the regex demo links in the answer above to see the difference between the two matches. Hope it helps

Comment: How can I check in another pattern if the String has 'x' inside it ?